# Iterating through string and replacing the spaces not working as expected

Tags: javascript, string, loops

So I'm trying to return the string with "%20" in between each space, except if there is a space at the beginning or end, where it will be removed instead (eg " Lighthouse Labs " becomes "Lighthouse%20Labs"). For some reason though, my first if statement isn't working, and if there is a space at the beginning or end, it applies the code inside the if statement to ALL the spaces and I have no idea why. I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something here. Any help appreciated!

```
const urlEncode = function (text) {
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(0) === " " || text.charAt(text.length - 1) === " ") {
      return text.split(" ").join("");
    } else {
      return text.split(" ").join("%20")
    }
  }
  return text;
};

console.log(urlEncode("Lighthouse Labs"));  // Lighthouse%20Labs

console.log(urlEncode(" Lighthouse Labs "));  // LighthouseLabs

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure")); //blue%20is%20greener%20than%20purple%20for%20sure

console.log(urlEncode(" blue is greener than purple for sure")); //blueisgreenerthanpurpleforsure

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure "));
//blueisgreenerthanpurpleforsure
```

Comment: I believe you can use use trim()

Comment: Is there a reason you are going through it by letter, rather than doing text.trim().replace(" ","%20") ?

Comment: Why not just use `.trim()` and then `.urlEncode()` or just a `.replace()`? You are reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: No reason, just pretty new to coding and thought this seemed like a decent solution

Comment: For the sake of argument, the main reason it's not working like you expect is because your first if statement should be outside of the loop.

Comment: There is already a function for that (`encodeURIComponent(..)`) and as the other have said, you can remove starting and trailing spaces using `String.trim()`.

Comment: Since you're new at coding, I'd suggest exploring the `String` API before beginning coding with strings to familiarize yourself with the methods available. Just a read-through of the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) will help to begin filling your toolbox.

Comment: Yeah I got latched onto using .split and ,join when I should have looked for better options. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim and replace:

```
const urlEncode = function (text) {
  const regex = / /g
  return text.trim().replace(regex, '%20');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this function:

```
const urlEncode = function (text){
    return text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '%20')
}
```

Trim() function will remove spaces from beginning and ending of text. The first argument of replace method is a regex that says every whitespace replaced by second argument, the `+` quantifier means that if there is consecutive whitespaces replace all of them with only one '%20'